# Как объявить переменную внутри цикла v-for?

Tags: vue.js

Необходимо, чтобы при проверке данных элементы внутри v-for проверялись на соответствие элементам массива polis_ltd_service и если условие верно, то должен отображаться первый элемент - а, а если не верно, то второй элемент a
Цикл v-for:

```
<ul class="list-group category-list mh-20 twocolumn"
    v-model="services">
    <li 
    v-for="(service, index) in services"
    class="list-serv pt-1"
    >
    {{ service }}
    <a
    v-if="isShown(index)">
    &#10004;
    </a>
    <a
    v-if="!isShown(index)">
    &#9940;
    </a>
    <button type="button" 
    class="btn"
    @click="services.splice(index, 1)"
    >x</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Код VueJS:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      companys, companys,
      poliss: [],
      services: [],
      polis_ltd_service: [],
      show: [],
      items: [],
      active: null,
      search: '',
      reqSer: '',
      isServ: undefined,
      tipStrah: false,
      subm: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isShown(i) {
      return this.show[i]
    },
    changeShow(i) {
      Vue.set(this.show, i, !this.show[i]);
    },
    enterService() {
      this.services.push(this.reqSer)
      this.reqSer = ''
      console.log(this.services)
    },
    submitForm() {
        this.services.forEach(service => {
          this.polis_ltd_service.polis_ltd_inservice.forEach(inservice => {
            if (service === inservice) {}          
          })
        })
    },
created() {
    axios.get('/src/api/company.json')
    .then(response => {
      this.poliss = response.data;
    })
    axios.get('/src/api/services.json')
    .then(response => {
      this.polis_ltd_service = response.data;
    })
    fakeFetch().then((items) => {
       this.items = items;
       this.show = this.items.map(() => false);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [2,1,2,3],
      checkValue: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkIn(item){
      return item === this.checkValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>


<div id="app" class="">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
          <div v-if="checkIn(item)">Прошел проверку</div>
          <div v-else> Не прошел проверку</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```